# Como mapear um auto-relacionamento usando o EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Minha entidade Pessoa também pode ser uma entidade Funcionário. Tenho a necessidade de que, sempre que eu cadastrar uma Pessoa, devo informar o FuncionarioId que a cadastrou, sendo PessoaId como Chave primária e PessoaFuncionarioId como Chave estrangeira. OBS: Só citei os campos de Id para a tabela não ficar grande.
Preciso fazer o mapeamento usando o EF Core, mas não sei como fazer isso. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

```
public class Pessoa : Entity
{
    public int PessoaId  { get; private set; }
    public int PessoaFuncionarioId  { get; private set; }
}


public class PessoaMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Pessoa> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Pessoa");

        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PessoaId")
            .HasColumnType("integer")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('\"PessoaIdSeq\"')")
            .IsRequired();

            //????????????????????


    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: só a caráter de curiosidade, como você adicionaria a primeira pessoa se ainda não ia ter nenhum funcionário que também é uma pessoa?

Comment: Primeiro eu adiciono o funcionario e depois as demais pessoas :)

Comment: é, eu vi ali depois no desenho que pode ser nulo, mas na sua classe a primeira coisa que precisaria era alterar de int pra int nullable, tô elaborando uma resposta aqui, já mando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conforme comentado, a primeira coisa a ser feito é tornar PessoaFuncionarioId  nullable e adicionar a própria classe como propriedade

```
public class Pessoa : Entity
{
    public int PessoaId  { get; private set; }
    public int? PessoaFuncionarioId  { get; private set; }
    public virtual Pessoa PessoaFuncionario  { get; private set; }
}
```

no mapping já fica mais simples, é só referenciar uma configuração um pra muitos

```
public class PessoaMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Pessoa>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Pessoa> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Pessoa");

        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PessoaId")
            .HasColumnType("integer")
            .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('\"PessoaIdSeq\"')")
            .IsRequired();

            //????????????????????

       builder.HasOne(_ => _.PessoaFuncionario)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.PessoaFuncionarioId)
            .IsRequired(false);

    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Lucas Miranda! :)